# Upgraded Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 and crashes at login screen

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, login-screen

<sup>Translated from Portuguese:</sup>

I was using version 18.04 and formatted and installed version 20.04, and now when I turn on the computer and the screen to enter the password appears, after I enter the password the screen freezes and the mouse does not move and the keyboard doesn't work, except for <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> which is the only thing that works.

In GRUB I choose the advanced options of Ubuntu and the second option, Ubuntu recovery mode, then the PC works normally.

This is a dual boot with Windows 10. I use a 240 GB SSD, on which I left 60 GB for Ubuntu.

Ryzen 5 2600 Rtx 2060 16 GB RAM.

Comment: Vote to re-open - Translated from Portuguese

Comment: @User24601 Done! Last lines still need some edits!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem while upgrading from Kubuntu 18.04 to Kubuntu 20.04.

My system is setup with two users apart from root. I could login with one of the non-root users (`xxx`), but not with the other (`yyy`). When looking into my `/home` tree, I recognized that all directories were owned by `xxx`.

To allow logging in with `yyy`, I used the command:

```
sudo chown -R yyy:yyy /home/yyy
```